# How to fix logging bot error [object Undefined]?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been trying to make a bot that logs everything in a specific channel. As I use this script, the bot posts "[object Undefined]" to the channel. If leave the toString out, the bot only posts the "User" part.

```javascript
client.channels.cache.get('843442692993318913').send(toString('User', message.author.username, message.author.id, 'used command in a channel', message.channel.name))
```

Could someone help me, I am a beginner in these things.

Comment: Is toString a function you created?

Comment: because if it's the default function it won't work like this

Comment: `toString` is a method for numbers and not a standalone function. You can use [`String()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp) function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `toString` function for this, use an interpolated string. Also I would recommend not using (or not only using) the bot's cache to find a channel. It can cause unexpected problems, so either use `resolve` per default or as a fallback:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('843442692993318913') ?? client.channels.resolve('843442692993318913');

channel.send(`User ${message.author.username} ${message.author.id} used command in a channel ${message.channel.name}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the other values as another parameters to toString()

Only the first one will be converted , which is 'user'

if You need other data as string ,you can use interpolated string

you define it between ``

Then add your variables and text like this:

```
`The Id : {$message.author.id}  -  The Username : ${message.author.username} - ...`
```

Comment: Yep you are right thanks, didn't notice , I edited it .